# Is this Dracaena reflexa?

Tags: identification, houseplants, dracaena

Dracaena reflexa? Does care requirement same for other dracaenas?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be called Dracenae demerensis 'Janet Craig' but has now been reclassified as a cultivar of  [Dracaena fragrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_fragrans). Members of this family:

- are sensitive to chlorine in city tap water
- respond well to being cut back
- happiest in bright diffused light
- respond to overwatering by getting brown spots on the leaves.
- the oldest specimens I saw were potted up with a good proportion of clay

Comment: Clay in pot? So this plants require good water and good light? How tolerant it is to winter? Can it survive around 6 C in winter?

Comment: @4-K  You can try using up to 50% clay based soil if available. Bake first to sterilize and remove any pathogens.  These are tropical plants and will not do well at 6 deg C.  I would not keep these plants below ~ 15 Deg C