# Dragon tree disease - need help identifying

Tags: identification, diseases

Last week my dragon tree after 3 years of non-issues started showing some signs of damage, can someone help me identify what it might be?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my answer [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/48778/499) regarding another member of the dracaena family

- are sensitive to chlorine in city tap water
- respond well to being cut back
- happiest in bright diffused light
- respond to overwatering by getting brown spots on the leaves.
- the oldest specimens I saw were potted up with a good proportion of clay

Your plant is likely to be either over watered or has been getting chlorinated tap water.

I see you have Leca clay balls on the top of the pot.  Is this a hydroponic plant?  If so, you can drain all the smelly water out and use distilled water once to remove the dissolved salts and chlorine. If it is not hydroponic then remove the leca balls as they keep the soil wet longer.